# Assembly: Comparing registers using Ja

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, compare

10. Which choices contain correct implementations of the following pseudocode? (Assume that all values are unsigned):

if( eax > ebx )
    mov dl,5;
else
    mov dl,6;

```
a.
    cmp eax,ebx
    ja  L1
    mov dl,6
    jmp L2
L1: mov dl,5
L2:
b.
    cmp eax,ebx
    ja  L1
    mov dl,5
    jmp L2
L1: mov dl,6
L2:
c.
    cmp eax,ebx
    jbe L2
    mov dl,5
    jmp L2
L1: mov dl,6
L2:
d.
    cmp eax,ebx
    jna L2
    mov dl,5
    jmp L1
L1: mov dl,6
L2
```

:
I'm confused on does the `cmp eax, ebx` do eax > ebx or ebx > eax. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Whenever you are confused about how an instruction works, consult the instruction set reference.

Answer (score 0):

`cmp eax, ebx` compares the two values and sets the various [flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) according to the result.

`ja` jumps if the carry and zero flags are cleared. That is, if the previous comparison did not evaluate to equal or below.